# На каком языке программирования лучше создавать компилятор для своего языка программирования?

Tags: c, pascal

Я просто хочу создать свой язык программирования("MorphLang"). Есть несколько языков для создания компилятора:
1. C (Я считаю что он может подходить для создания компилятора).
2. Pascal (На нём пишут компиляторы для языков программирования, но это не для меня).
3. Сам MorphLang (Если создавать на нём, то объясните как).
Лучше чтобы создавать на самом MorphLang. Спасибо за советы.

Comment: Читайте The Dragon Book и будет вам счастье...

Comment: Вы уверены, что хотите именно компилятор, а не интерпретатор ? А так в общем то на C, когда первую минимальную версию сделаете, остальное можете делать уже на нем самом, главное, что бы возможностей начальной версии хватало для описания более продвинутой

Comment: На любом можно. Все современные языки (ну, за исключением HTML и тому подобных языков разметки) тьюринг-полны. «На Паскале пишут только компиляторы простых языков» — это над вами кто-то пошутил. Пишите на том, какой знаете.

Comment: Я собираюсь создавать компилятор если что, но никак не интерпретатор.

Comment: @Morphius Вы хорошо знаете ассемблер той платформы, для которой будет компилироваться код ?

Comment: Чтобы не писать велосипед, [воспользуйтесь фреймворком LLVM](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/746225/208074) и напишите frontend для своего языка. На Хабрахабре есть даже цикл статей, посвящённый этому: «[Создание языка программирования с использованием LLVM](https://habrahabr.ru/search/?target_type=&order_by=&q=%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5+%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B0+%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F+%D1%81+%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC+LLVM)».

Comment: @Mike, берём LLVM либо что-то подобное и забываем об оптимизаторе и кодогенерации (так как всё это уже реализовано под различные процессоры).

Comment: `Лучше чтобы создавать на самом MorphLang` —  это называется «bootstrapping» и его методы [перечислены в той же Википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0).